# Get object element from a defined string

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

how to get data from object with define string?

case:

```
  var data = [
  {name:"Sharma",country:"India"},
  {name:"Udin",country:"Indonesia"},
  {name:"John Carter",country:"Mars"}
  ];

  getData(data,"country");

  function getData(data,element){
    console.log(data[1].element);
  }
```

i want to get country but result is **undefinded**, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getData(data,element){
    console.log(data[1][element]);
  }
```

That's the correct way to access the value by using a key that is a string.

Comment: thanks dude, its awesome

Answer (score 2):

You would need to know both the index and the property

```
function getData(data,index,element){
    console.log(data[index][element]);
}

getData(data,1,"country");
```

Comment: You will need to index into the array still (`data` is an array) - perhaps he should have a parameter specifying the index...?

Comment: You are right, I misread the question.**Updated**